# How to manage footer while converting html to docx file using libreoffice command?

Tags: libreoffice, html-to-pdf, html-to-docx

I am trying to covert my html template to docx and pdf file.I want to add fix footer for all pages. I am using **libreoffice** command for it.

sudo -u ${user} libreoffice --headless --convert-to docx:"MS Word 2007 XML" ${htmlfilePath} --outdir ${destinationPath}

Thank you

Comment: So, you are trying, and what is the problem with it ?

Comment: If html content is around 20-25 page, how to add footer content for each page. Html content and content length is not fixed.